# Alternative to page-break-after: left in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing, page-break

To this day Firefox does not support page-break-after: left, which will assign one or two page breaks, ensuring the next page ends up on the left sheet you are printing (see [bug #132035](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132035)).

I have a script that ties hundreds of reports together, which someone will be generating and then printing out. The reports will be being printed on duplex, and no new report can end up on the back side of the previous report.

I have to run this in Firefox, and while page-break-after: left seems to be the perfect solution, it doesn't work.

Are there any alternatives that allows one to detect what page # one is at, so I can manually add an additional page-break-after:always tag when the next report starts on an even numbered page?

Comment: I'm afraid HTML is not the right tool for this job. It sounds like this should be a PDF generating project, not HTML.

Comment: Yeah, PDF would be much better, I am however locked in to doing it this way, as I am manipulating the DOM of two HTML reports I have no control over, combining them and then rendering them.